# Best method to resize network images in android for gridview

Tags: android, image, performance, gridview

What is the best way to resize network images in android to show in android `GridView`. I've nearly 100 images to show in grid view. Each image is `1024*1024` resolution images. Kindly suggest the bet way to load these images into grid view with out getting `out of memory` error. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Picasso for Image transformations.
http://square.github.io/picasso/

```
    IMAGE TRANSFORMATIONS
```

Transform images to better fit into layouts and to reduce memory size.

```
    Picasso.with(context)
   .load(url)
   .resize(50, 50)
   .centerCrop()
   .into(imageView)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I've managed with Glide. Let me see the improvement. Once again thanks for your valuable suggestion.